# HTTP server behind IIS: pass authentication headers

Tags: iis, authentication, http-headers, reverse-proxy, basic-authentication

I have an IIS instance configured with Windows Authentication and URL Rewrite, so it basically works as a reverse proxy. My backend server (run on Linux) expects a `REMOTE_USER` header. Is it possible to configure IIS to pass information about the authenticated user to the backend server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If IIS is configured for `Windows Auth`, then `ARR` will challenge and only forward requests once the user is authenticated.

It is possible to forward custom headers with the request using a `HTTP` naming convention and `serverVariables` element in the rewrite rules. For instance, in the following example the server variable `LOCAL_ADDR` is forwarded as a header named `X-MY-HEADER`.

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy to MySite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^MySite/(.*)" />
   <serverVariables>
      <set name="HTTP_X_MY_HEADER" value="{LOCAL_ADDR}" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.myothersite.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to use this technique to forward a `REMOTE_USER` header. This is because when the `Authorization` header is present, the request is forwarded before the authentication module runs, and therefore auth server variables are not set (when mapped to headers they simply come through blank).

You can however set IIS to use `Basic Windows Auth`, and then extract the username from the `Base64` encoded `Authorization` header on your Linux server.

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar problem and I thought I would mention how I managed to work around it. I have installed [Helicon ISAPI-Rewrite 3 Lite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/download.html), which is an ISAPI request filter. Since it runs after the authentication stage in the pipeline, it has access to the `REMOTE_USER` variable and can rewrite the request such that a new HTTP header is added to it with `REMOTE_USER` as its value. Of course this helps only if you have some control over the backend server so you can make use of the value of this custom header instead of the original `REMOTE_USER` variable.

The required snippet in ISAPI-Rewrite's global configuration file (`httpd.conf`) is as follows:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/MySite.*
RewriteHeader X-Remote-User: .* %{REMOTE_USER}
```

The `RewriteCond` part limits this rule to URIs starting with `/MySite`; feel free to adjust it as needed.